# How to get Squid to allow access based on referral?

Tags: domain, proxy, authentication, squid

I have a very specific need of allowing access to an unknown set of domains where they all have a common domain as referral.

Put the other way around I have a website including items (js, images, css, etc) from an unknown set of domains which I need to allow access through to.

I know referrals are set client side and can be edited. This is not a concern in this case as the users are already authenticated via credentials and logged.

Is allowing access based on referral possible in Squid?

Comment: @Bart De Vos, A "Thank you." being removed from the question? You have too much spare time.

Comment: It takes seconds, I always do it when I read a question. It's a guideline: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/876/edit-powers-activate-removing-hi-thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, using the referer acl-type - quoting the [manual](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/acl/):

```
acl aclname referer_regex [-i] regexp ...
  # pattern match on Referer header [fast]
  # Referer is highly unreliable, so use with care
```

An example configuration that should work:

```
acl myreferer referer_regex -i ^http://www.example.org
http_access allow myreferer
```

Comment: Is this correct?  I thought `.` was a metacharacter for `any character`